# How to get all tweets from a public account by BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, twitter, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all tweets from a given account but I can get only last 20 tweets. How can I get all the tweets that user posted ?
Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib

#This function returns tweets from
#given username's account as a list
def get_tweets(username):
    tweets = []
    URL = "https://twitter.com/"+username
    soup = bs(urllib.request.urlopen(URL), 'lxml')

    for li in soup.find_all("li", {"data-item-type": "tweet"}):
        text_p = li.find("p", class_="tweet-text")
        if text_p is not None:
            tweets.append(text_p.get_text())
    return tweets
```

Comment: Why not use a Twitter python API like Twython?

Comment: I will try, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In [Tweepy](http://www.tweepy.org/), you can get the user's timeline like this:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, username).items():
    print('status_id: {}, text: {}'.format(status.id, status.text.encode('utf-8')))
```

Notice that it's using `Tweepy.Cursor`, which iterates through the list until there aren't any more items.